# MySql - Finding "today" and "yesterday" while using CONVERT_TZ

Tags: mysql, convert-tz

I am struggling to get the correct definition of "today" and "yesterday" while using CONVERT_TZ() in MySql.  My dates are stored in UTC, and I need to query the dates coming out in MST timezone, so something like this produces the correct start time of the day:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(convert_tz(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00','-07:00'), '%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00')
```

However, when I put it into a query, it doesn't seem to work.

This query correctly produces the last 24 hours, but not "today" (i.e. the time from midnight to now).

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(insertdate,'+00:00','-07:00') >= convert_tz(DATE_SUB(utc_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'+00:00','-07:00')
```

Then in similar form, this produces a query that is the 24 hours before 24 hours ago, but isn't "yesterday" (i.e. yesterday from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 of yesterday's date in MST timezone).

```
select * from tablename  
AND  CONVERT_TZ(insertdate,'+00:00','-07:00') >= convert_tz(DATE_SUB(utc_timestamp(), INTERVAL 2 DAY),'+00:00','-07:00')
AND  CONVERT_TZ(insertdate,'+00:00','-07:00') <= convert_tz(DATE_SUB(utc_timestamp(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'+00:00','-07:00')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format your date using date_format function and set the time as "00:00:00" query for today is 
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(insertdate,'+00:00','-07:00') >= date_format(convert_tz(utc_timestamp(),'+00:00','-07:00'), '%y-%m-%d 00:00:00');

Yesterday: 
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(insertdate,'+00:00','-07:00') between  date_format(convert_tz(date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 1 day),'+00:00','-07:00'), '%y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format(convert_tz(date_sub(utc_timestamp(), interval 1 day),'+00:00','-07:00'), '%y-%m-%d 23:59:59');